# The .gitignore setting for the .idea folder of Jetbrains Rider's does not work

Tags: git, unity-game-engine, gitignore, rider, github-desktop

I am currently working on a game project for Android using Unity and Rider on Windows10. Git administration is using Github Desktop.

After completing the game production, I tried to set up .gitignore to upload to Github, I connected to gitignore.io and selected windows, unity, jetbrains + all, and then entered .gitignore in my .gitignore which is displayed on the screen. The link to the code is https://www.gitignore.io/api/unity,windows,jetbrains+all.

The code below is the .gitignore code I wrote down.

```html
# Created by https://www.gitignore.io/api/unity,windows,jetbrains+all
# Edit at https://www.gitignore.io/?templates=unity,windows,jetbrains+all

### JetBrains+all ###
# Covers JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, RubyMine, PhpStorm, AppCode, PyCharm, CLion, Android Studio and WebStorm
# Reference: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839

# User-specific stuff
.idea/**/workspace.xml
.idea/**/tasks.xml
.idea/**/usage.statistics.xml
.idea/**/dictionaries
.idea/**/shelf

# Generated files
.idea/**/contentModel.xml

# Sensitive or high-churn files
.idea/**/dataSources/
.idea/**/dataSources.ids
.idea/**/dataSources.local.xml
.idea/**/sqlDataSources.xml
.idea/**/dynamic.xml
.idea/**/uiDesigner.xml
.idea/**/dbnavigator.xml

# Gradle
.idea/**/gradle.xml
.idea/**/libraries

# Gradle and Maven with auto-import
# When using Gradle or Maven with auto-import, you should exclude module files,
# since they will be recreated, and may cause churn.  Uncomment if using
# auto-import.
# .idea/modules.xml
# .idea/*.iml
# .idea/modules

# CMake
cmake-build-*/

# Mongo Explorer plugin
.idea/**/mongoSettings.xml

# File-based project format
*.iws

# IntelliJ
out/

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin
.idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin
atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Cursive Clojure plugin
.idea/replstate.xml

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ)
com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml
crashlytics.properties
crashlytics-build.properties
fabric.properties

# Editor-based Rest Client
.idea/httpRequests

# Android studio 3.1+ serialized cache file
.idea/caches/build_file_checksums.ser

### JetBrains+all Patch ###
# Ignores the whole .idea folder and all .iml files
# See https://github.com/joeblau/gitignore.io/issues/186 and https://github.com/joeblau/gitignore.io/issues/360

.idea/

# Reason: https://github.com/joeblau/gitignore.io/issues/186#issuecomment-249601023

*.iml
modules.xml
.idea/misc.xml
*.ipr

### Unity ###
[Ll]ibrary/
[Tt]emp/
[Oo]bj/
[Bb]uild/
[Bb]uilds/
Assets/AssetStoreTools*

# Visual Studio cache directory
.vs/

# Autogenerated VS/MD/Consulo solution and project files
ExportedObj/
.consulo/
*.csproj
*.unityproj
*.sln
*.suo
*.tmp
*.user
*.userprefs
*.pidb
*.booproj
*.svd
*.pdb
*.opendb
*.VC.db

# Unity3D generated meta files
*.pidb.meta
*.pdb.meta

# Unity3D Generated File On Crash Reports
sysinfo.txt

# Builds
*.apk
*.unitypackage

### Windows ###
# Windows thumbnail cache files
Thumbs.db
ehthumbs.db
ehthumbs_vista.db

# Dump file
*.stackdump

# Folder config file
[Dd]esktop.ini

# Recycle Bin used on file shares
$RECYCLE.BIN/

# Windows Installer files
*.cab
*.msi
*.msix
*.msm
*.msp

# Windows shortcuts
*.lnk

# End of https://www.gitignore.io/api/unity,windows,jetbrains+all
```

However, some of the files in the .idea folder are different from the .gitignore settings. So I left this question. As far as I know, the subdirectory of the .idea folder should not be registered with git, but I wonder if it is normal to see some files. If this is not normal, it will ask you if you want to add all the .idea folder sub-lists to .gitignore.

The picture below is a picture taken from Github Desktop.

[image]

I will be waiting for a good answer. Thanks for reading.

Comment: This question is more about which files are relevant to track than on how to use git.I would not have used the git tag.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The reason that this folder is not ignored since it stores the configuration of your project and due to that it's not part of the default `.gitignore`

You can fix it in no time.

---

Explaining how to do from the command line, can be done via IDEA as well.

```
# Once the files are committed adding them to .gitignore will not help,
# you must remove them from the index
# Remove the file from the repository
git rm --cached .idea/

# now update your gitignore file to ignore this folder
echo '.idea' >> .gitignore

# add the .gitignore file to your index
git add .gitignore

git commit -m "Removed .idea files"
git push origin <branch>
```

Comment: Thank you. Thanks to Responder, if the file is already in git and is tracking, I need to clear the cache. Thank you for your reply and hope you have a good day today.

Comment: Good luck, and yes follow the script it will fix it for you. i wrote there all you will need

Comment: Not answering the question

Answer (score 1):

```
echo ".idea/*" >> ~/.gitignore
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore
```